# Windows Server 2008R2 Inconsistent TLS 1.2 Connection

Tags: .net, payment-gateway, windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2

I've researched this quite thoroughly but can't seem to find the nugget that fixes my problem.

I'm running a .NET 4.6.1 application on Windows Server 2008R2 Standard. The application makes a secure call to a payment gateway server, this call needs to use TLS 1.2 and the payment gateway are in the process of shutting down TLS 1.0 access to their service. I've made all the recommended changes to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on my server.

The behaviour that I'm getting is that the Client Hello from my server is only offering TLS 1.0 to the payment gateway and as is result the payment gateway is refusing the connection. The strange thing is that when I use a different payment gateway (PayPal) that also only accepts TLS 1.2 (this is using the same application) the Client Hello offers TLS 1.2 and it's accepted. Stranger still is that having achieved a successful TLS 1.2 connection with PayPal when I now attempt to connect to the original payment gateway the Client Hello offers TLS 1.2 and the connection is accepted. This then works for a while but eventually falls back to only offering TLS 1.0 in the Client Hello.

Here's what I've done so far without any luck:

- Windows Update is bang up to date
- RegEdit. [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
  "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
- Ditto for TLS 1.1
- RegEdit. [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
  "DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000a00

I can provide Wireshark logs

Comment: If the problem was with the server, Paypal wouldn't work either. Client applications negotiate with the server starting from their default TLS version downwards. In 4.6 that's TLS1.2. Are you setting System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in code anywhere, or in a library? That's a global setting. You can also try to set it to Tls12 *only*, to refuse to connect to anything else

Comment: Or it may be that the *server* has issues and the negotiation falls back to TLS1.0. My experience with payment gateways is ... mixed to say the least. You may be getting redirected from a TLS1.0 endpoint to a TLS1.2 only.

Comment: Im not setting System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol at all in the application. My understanding was that in 4.6.1 the default was TLS 1.2.

Comment: Then try setting it to TLS1.2 on startupt to *refuse* anything below that. If that works you'll know that the problem may be caused by the negotiation process.

Comment: I think the problem is with my server as the Client Hello seems to be only offering 1.0. It's not being downgraded by the handshake with the payment gateway server.

Comment: In that case Paypal wouldn't work either.

Comment: Adding: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; to the code appears to have resolved the problem. I need to do some more checking before I fully confirm.